# Accessing variable from string name

Tags: c#, string, variables

I am accessing this variable `Der`, which I can get or set through the local `_der`.

The `SetValues` gets a string name on the parameter that is wanted to change(and a list that the local list should be set to)

The string comes with the "global" datastore name, which I change to the local (Der->_der).

Now, how do I in `SetValues`, "convert" the string name `lParam`, to the actual local parameter that I want to set?

Hope u understand and can help

```
[Subscribe]
public StorableList<double> Der{
    get{return _der;}
    set{_der = value;}
}

public static string ConvertToLocalParameter(string input) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("ARGH");
    }

    return "_" + char.ToLower(input[0]) + input.Substring(1);
}

public void SetValues(string listName, StorableList<double> values) {
    string lParam = ConvertToLocalParameter(listName);
}

private StorableList<double> _der;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: sorry - done - C# it is

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct (and this is java), you could use reflection

```
Field field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField(lParam);

field.set(this, values);
```

But if you only have a limited amount of such values you could just use a few if's in your method to set the value

---

Edit: If it's C#, you can read about [Reflection in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial)

Comment: my project do not  like this using System.Data.DataSetExtensions; which seems to be needed - the Library.Containers - does provide a field class but not with the methods in ur example 
i am developing for Windows CE - if that matters?

Comment: it is about 10 different inputs atm i can get - but i can say how many in the future  - and for ease i would like it to be just the subscriptions added to the class that is needed when adding a new variable - i thought about just using a switch case based on the string - but more code - having to write code 2 places instead of one with new variables ...

Comment: does it change anything that these varaiables will always be of the type StorableList<double>?

Comment: It has to be always StorableList<double> otherwise you wouldn't be able to insert your value in there (because yuor value is Storable<double> )